# How do I update the B2B price of an offer, using SPAPI?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Trying to find a way to change the B2B price for an offer.

I know I can change the B2C price using patchListingItem API (Listings Items API v2021-08-01) with "op": "replace" and "path": "/attributes/purchasable_offer".

```
"purchasable_offer": [
      {
        "currency": "USD",
        "our_price": [
          {
            "schedule": [
              {
                "value_with_tax": 90.00
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

But what about the B2B price and Automated Pricing (Enable, Min/Max)?

Which attributes should be used?